# How to insert after 2nd element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert something after the second form with `mform` class, for this markup:

```
<table id="sortme">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><form class="mform"></form></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><form class="mform"></form><!---Insert Me here !---></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><form class="mform"></form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To insert after the first form, I can use:

```
$(function () {
$('<div>block</div>').insertAfter("#sortme form.mform:first");
});
```

so I've tried this code for the second, didn't work:

```
$(function () {
$('<div>block</div>').insertAfter("#sortme > form.mform:nth-child(2)");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `.insertAfter("#sortme form.mform:eq(1)");`

Comment: thanks, your first suggestion worked, second one doesn't though, what's the difference?

Comment: @rockyraw - The one I've deleted won't work, just realized that

Answer (score 1):

You, also, may use a `counter`, conditional statement and `append` as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      counter = 0;
      $(".mform").each(function(){
        if (counter === 1){
          $(this).append("<div>Block</div>");
        }
        counter++;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

A demo is [HERE](http://jsbin.com/todoqufoti/edit?html,output)

Comment: FYI - You can also get the current index by passing it to the `.each()` callback function (`$(".mform").each(function(index){`) - and check `if( index === 1)`